# Error:(7, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@color/accentColor')

Tags: android, android-studio, colors

Were running the sample file, the above error occurs.
I do not know how to solve.

[image]

Comment: Have you `colors.xml` in your project? `@color/accent` should be defined here

Comment: @이은채 : Post your `color.xml` here..!!

Comment: Then try clean e rebuild your project

Comment: add in to color.xml <color name="colorAccent">ADD_COLOR</color>

Answer (score 1):

Add follwing resource to your **colors.xml**

```
<color name="colorAccent">YOUR_COLOR</color>
```

This may resolve your issue.