# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@color/Accent')

Tags: android, xml

I develop an Android app but i get almost exactly the same error like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178610/error7-34-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-coloraccent-wi/37917881#37917881)
with: No resource found that Matches the given Name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@Color/accent').

as descript here (link) I have no colors.xml file in my Project. But i have found in my Android.sdk that i have there two colors.xml files. should i use one of these? or do i have to create a new colors.xml file. If i have to create a new file can you tell me what i have to write into the file?

I'm a beginner in Programm resp. App developing so I hope you have a little understanding for me. I use Visual Studio with Xamarin v4.1

I hope anyone could help me ;)

Here you see my Strings.xml Code file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#00FFAA</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#004D40</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. 
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#00897B</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#1DE9B6</item>-->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You have to define colors in res/values/colors.xml. They can be accessed via `@color/colorName`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to create your own colors (values/colors.xml) with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
    <color name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</color>
</resources>
```

replace "white" with what suits you most, and you can access it in layout xmls using @color/colorAccent or from java as R.color.colorAccent

Answer (score 4):

Add this code your `/res/values/colors.xml`

```
<resources>   
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked in my case was, /res/values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

In file AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/red" />
```

Remember you need to achieve these values in those xml by editing android.json file. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an ancient thread, but....

The more modern substitution for @color/colorAccent is to use ?attr/colorAccent.  This will use whatever is the accent color for the current theme.

Here is an example from an layout XML file:

android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this issue using ionic 5.

I needed just a quick solution, so it works for me:

add to `AndroidManifes.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:value="#FF4081"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use your own **colors.xml** (in folder res\values). If you want use Android standard colors, you can use them in the next way (for example):

```
<item name="testColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

Comment: platforms\android\res\values\colors.xml: Error: Unsupported node 'item'